# Flutter with Wordpress backend...Good or Bad...?

Tags: wordpress, flutter

What are the limitations/disadvantages of using WordPress as backend for flutter...?

Can this combination effectively used for advanced sites like ecommerce/membership without taking hit on performance...?

Thank You

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Aren't these type of questions allowed here...? I am a beginner just asking opinion from experts here before diving in...

Comment: @AlanGautham https://i.redd.it/cytow1s4lzt81.png